# What is the use of callbacks/callables in PHP?

Tags: php, callback, callable

I am trying to wrap my head around what callbacks are or do in PHP.

I have seen the documentation, but what they useful for?

Is there something that callbacks do that can't be done in simple functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks are used to allow us to apply custom logic to generic functions like `usort()` for array sorting, if we want a more complex sorting logic than the basic sorting functions provide... e.g. sorting an array of objects by a specific property. Using a callback, we can define the sort rule.

This can be defined using standard PHP function, that we've created

```
$data = [
    (object) ['myDate' => '2017-01-12'],
    (object) ['myDate' => '2016-12-25'],
    (object) ['myDate' => '2017-01-01'],
];

function dateSort($a, $b) {
    return $a->myDate <=> $b->myDate;
}

usort($data, 'dateSort');
var_dump($data);
```

or using an anonymous function

```
$data = [
    (object) ['myDate' => '2017-01-12'],
    (object) ['myDate' => '2016-12-25'],
    (object) ['myDate' => '2017-01-01'],
];

usort($data, function($a, $b) { return $a->myDate <=> $b->myDate; });
var_dump($data);
```

so the callback that we apply to `usort()` allows us to apply that complex logic, which the other `sort()` functions cannot use.

---

Anonymous functions give us much more flexibility: the callback used by many of the array functions like `usort()` or `array_filter()` automatically receives certain arguments from the function, e.g. `usort()` is passed two values from the array for ordering... not a problem if you're simply comparing those two values, you can create a simple function and use that; but what happens if we want to sort, pivoted about a certain value, like `2016-12-31`, so we're sorting on the number of days until/since that date; we need a new function, one which has that date hard-coded in it as the pivot value:

```
$data = [
    (object) ['myDate' => '2017-01-12'],
    (object) ['myDate' => '2016-12-25'],
    (object) ['myDate' => '2017-01-01'],
];

function dateSort($a, $b) {
    return abs(strtotime('2016-12-31') - strtotime($a->myDate)) <=> abs(strtotime('2016-12-31') - strtotime($b->myDate));
}

usort($data, 'dateSort');
var_dump($data);
```

And now we get to the fun part, what happens if we want to dynamically allocate our pivot date value? We can't pass any additional arguments to the `usort()` callback, so how do we pass a pivot value of '2017-01-06' or '2017-12-26' at runtime? Here's where an anonymous callback is particularly useful, because we can easily pass dditional arguments to the anonymous function via `use`:

```
$data = [
    (object) ['myDate' => '2017-01-12'],
    (object) ['myDate' => '2016-12-25'],
    (object) ['myDate' => '2017-01-01'],
];


$pivotDate = '2017-01-06';
usort(
    $data,
    function ($a, $b) use ($pivotDate){
        return abs(strtotime($pivotDate) - strtotime($a->myDate)) <=> abs(strtotime($pivotDate) - strtotime($b->myDate));
});
var_dump($data);
```